Qatar Visa issue: Am I medically unfit?
I already applied for a visa to Qatar in August and October 2023 for work. My visa was rejected because my Hepatitis B virus PCR test was positive, but now I am undergoing treatment and my HBV PCR test is negative (not detected).
Can I apply for a visa again? I was told not to apply because I would be banned if I did, but is this right?

While it is commonly agreed that repeated visa refusals themselves make a future refusal more likely, you do have a change in circumstances which might lead to a different result. Who gave you this advice? Are they trustworthy and experienced in Qatar visa issues and procedures?

What type of employment are you seeking? Since hepatitis B is treatable but not curable, the type of work you intend to do may mean you are ineligible.

@Traveller I doubt whether Qatar will allow you to work. One example I see is for Singapore, they won't allow anyone with HIV to work or hold long term passes, for any work. I am assuming Qatar is more restrictive and may just ban him.
